# sorting is not working in angularjs when i click on first column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

when i try to sort the data while clicking on column header, data is not sorting when i click in first column header, the data is sorting only for first two columns, could anybody knows where is am wrong actually!
this is my controller code
`var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');

```
      $scope.gridTestData = [{ "firstname": "john", "lastname": "Jackson", "gender": "M", "status": "1" }, { "firstname": "jr", "lastname": "Jackson", "gender": "F", "status": "0" }, { "firstname": "robort", "lastname": "jr", "gender": "M", "status": "1" }];

$scope.order = function(predicate) {
  $scope.predicate = predicate;
  $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
  $scope.gridTestData = orderBy($scope.gridTestData, predicate, $scope.reverse);
};
$scope.order('age', true);`
```

[This is my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PSp5iGm4Z8oqJku8orIe?p=preview)

Comment: I think it is sorting, just you cannot see as the values are the same for both direction :)

Comment: Thanks i didn't see the data :P